# Open JFrame on same screen(monitor) as JavaFX' 8 dialog

Tags: java, swing, javafx-8

I am working on application that has a usual login window (JavaFX' 8 dialog), and then on accept it opens new window (JFrame). If it runs in multi-monitor environment, it should work the way, that JFrame would be opened on the same monitor where JavaFX' 8 dialog was closed.

Right now I could open JFrame on monitor that I can choose manually using 
 `GraphicsEnvironment`, but at this point I can't figure out on which monitor JavaFX' 8 dialog was closed. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: [JFrame needs a `GraphicsConfiguration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#JFrame-java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration-) to initialize it on a different monitor and since JavaFX uses [Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html#getScreens--) to achieve the same result, it is not very easy to link these two. Are you bound to use a JFrame? Why can't you use a [SwingNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html) instead?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm bounded to use a JFrame, but thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is what worked for me:

```
/**
* As an argument you pass a Scene(of Java FX 8 Dialog in my example),
* by closing it you want JFrame to open on same monitor.
**/
public static int getActiveStageLocation(Scene scene){
    List interScreens = Screen.getScreensForRectangle(scene.getWindow().getX(),
            scene.getWindow().getY(),
            scene.getWindow().getWidth(),
            scene.getWindow().getHeight());
    Screen activeScreen = (Screen) interScreens.get(0);
    Rectangle2D r = activeScreen.getBounds();
    double position = r.getMinX();
    return (int) position;
}
```

Then you simple set location of your JFrame:

```
/**
* Some code for instantiating frame and so on....
* Parameter scene you could get for example from your FXML
**/
myFrame.setLocation(getActiveStageLocation(scene), myFrame.getY());
myFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could save your Position when you close your JavaFX dialog:

```
private void saveWindowPosition() {
    Preferences userPrefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(getClass());
    userPrefs.putDouble("stage.x", primaryStage.getX());
    userPrefs.putDouble("stage.y", primaryStage.getY());
}
```

and read it out like this:

```
private void restoreWindowPosition() {
    Preferences userPrefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(getClass()); 
    // get window location from user preferences: use x=100, y=100 as
    // default
    double x = userPrefs.getDouble("stage.x", 100);
    double y = userPrefs.getDouble("stage.y", 100);

    primaryStage.setX(x);
    primaryStage.setY(y);
}
```

Comment: As ItachiUchiha replied, Swing and JavaFX use different ways to open window on different monitor, so your approach doesn't work.